# How to run espeak command when I click on a link in a website on a Raspberry pi

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi, cgi

I need help. I built a robot using Raspberry pi and then expanded it with a camera and a speaker.
I installed a lighthttpd server and I can control it using a simple website.

It works fine, the webserver presents this site: https://github.com/Mjrovai/MJRoBot-Web-RPi-Robot/blob/master/index.html and when a button is clicked a cgi script start a motor. For example forward.cgi (edited https://github.com/Mjrovai/MJRoBot-Web-RPi-Robot/blob/master/cgi-bin/forward.cgi) script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio mode 7 out
gpio mode 0 out
gpio mode 2 out
gpio mode 3 out
gpio write 7 0
gpio write 0 1
gpio write 2 0
gpio write 3 1
```

When above script runs it sets each GPIO and motors starts.

What I'm trying to do now is to add a function when I press a button another cgi script will be used to generate some speech. The problem I am having is even if I add a below command to above file it runs the motors but it doesn't speak.

```
espeak test
```

I tried with PHP. I used below index.php file to trigger speak.sh when link is clicked but it doesn't work.

index.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  exec("speak.sh");
}
?>

<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>
```

speak.sh (copied from stackoverflow.com)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  announce  -  script to convert text parameter into spoken sound
#
#  Prerequisites:
#  eSpeak
#  mbrola binary
#  mbrola voice
#  alsa sound
#  libportaudio
#
#  Axel Kemper  21-Feb-2015
#
#==================================================================
#

get_abs_dir() {
  echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")" && pwd)"
}

set_volume() {
  #  "amixer scontrols" lists all simple ALSA controls
  #  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/amixer.1.html
  amixer set Headphone $1 > /dev/null
  amixer set Headphone $2 > /dev/null
  amixer set PCM $1 > /dev/null
  amixer set PCM $2 > /dev/null
}

text=$*
amplitude=100      #  0 .. 200   default: 100
pitch=50           #  0 .. 99    default: 50
wordsPerMinute=90  #  80 .. 450  default: 175
charFormat=2       #  8-bit character set
charFormat=1       #  UTF-8 character set
soundDevice=sysdefault  #  cf. aplay -L
esHome=$(get_abs_dir $0)
esHome=${esHome%/bin}

voice=en+m3       #   "de+f2"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$esHome/shared_library

set_volume 100% on
#  espeak-data has to reside in $esHome
espeak -a $amplitude -p $pitch -b $charFormat -v $voice "text" --stdout | aplay -D$soundDevice &$
```

The above code, when run in terminal it produces sound, but when run in a webserver it doesn't. Is ther any way I can run any command from a website? Yes, I am aware of security implications about this.  I am not a developer and trying to learn so any ideas welcomed.

Also is there a way to create a site with a field to type the text which then raspberry pi would speak using espeak?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show how you start `forward.cgi` and how `Index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

I added below to the /etc/sudoers file and it works. Yes, I understand the security implications behind this so please don't do this in a production environment.

```
Cmnd_Alias ESPEAK_CMDS = /usr/bin/espeak
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ESPEAK_CMDS
```

Also check /var/log/syslog for more details